# Site/Fórum sobre Python

Tags: python

Meu questionamento não é exatamente sobre algum código, mas sobre aonde posso discutir sobre.
Estou iniciando em Python e as vezes tenho alguma dúvidas ou questionamentos que não cabem serem perguntados no Stack Overflow, como informações sobre equipes, formas de aprendizado, etc.

A pergunta é a seguinte, quais sites, fóruns e comunidades de qualidade e ativas sobre python posso acompanhar durante este meu período de iniciação?
De preferência em português, pois pretendo discutir projetos mais aprofundados e formar equipes mais pra frente.

Caso este tipo de pergunta não se encaixe com os padrões do site me avisem que a retiro.
Obrigado.